# Не срабатывает событие кнопки при очистке текстового поля

Tags: c#, test-automation

Добрый день.
Есть кнопка, которая disabled по умолчанию.
При введении цифр в текстовое поле, кнопка становится активной.
При удалении введенных цифр - кнопка снова disabled.
При мануальном воспроизведении шагов все срабатывает как описано.
При запуске автотеста - при очищении текстового поля кнопка НЕ становится disabled, что отображается в браузере.

```
[Category("ButtonDisabledWhenTextBoxCleared")]                
[TestCase()]
public void TextButtonDisabledWhenTextBoxCleared()
{
    IWebElement field = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("id"));
    field.SendKeys("12345");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    field.Clear();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    var act =  =_driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).GetAttribute("disabled");     
    Assert.AreEqual("true", act);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
В автотестировании первые шаги, не судите строго.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете Thread.Sleep(), чтобы задержать выполнение программы, пока страница не отреагирует на действие. Это не гарантирует, что все асинхронные действия на странице завершатся в заданные интервалы. Вместо этого, лучше использовать WebDriverWait, чтобы дождаться определенных условий на странице, прежде чем продолжить выполнение теста.